# Pairwise independence, mutual independence and higher order interactions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, random-variables, independence

Could you help me to show the following:

"Consider the random variables $X,Y$ i.i.d. uniform on $[-1,1]$. Then $(X,Y,XY)$ are pairwise independent but mutually dependent. "

I am confused about pairwise independent: how can $X,XY$ be pairwise independent?

---

I would also appreciate some more general clarification on pairwise independence, mutual independence and higher order interactions:
I am reading [here](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/4893-a-kernel-test-for-three-variable-interactions.pdf), page 1:

"*Tests of total (mutual) and pairwise independence are insufficient, however, since they do not rule out all **third** order factorizations of the joint distribution.
An important class of high order interactions occurs when the simultaneous effect of two variables
on a third **may not be additive**. In particular, it may be possible that $X\perp Y$ and $Y\perp Z$,
whereas $(X,Y)\perp Z$ does not hold.*''

- the adjective "*third*" in the expression "*third order factorizations*" comes from the fact that I am considering 3 variables? So, if I have 4 variables then I have also fourth orderfactorizations? What is exactly intended as third (or higher) order factorizations?
- What does it mean that the effect of a variable on another is *additive*? Is the example above reporting an additive effect? It seems multiplicative.
- "*in particular, it may be possible that $X\perp Y$ and $Y\perp Z$,
  whereas $(X,Y)\perp Z$ does not hold.*" Isn/t this case captured as well by the mutual dependence situations mentioned above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems your source is wrong or at least uses a very unfortunate example to get its point across. $XY$ and $X$ are independent if knowledge of $X$ does not influence the probability distribution of $XY$, but this breaks down in the special (probability zero) case that $X = 0$.

A better example is if $X$ and $Y$ are drawn independently from $\{-1, 1\}$ (so the 2 element set instead of the interval) where $1$ and $-1$ have equal probability for both $X$ and $Y$. Now a priori $XY$ has prob 1/2 of being -1 and prob 1/2 of being one, and after observing the value of $X$ (whatever it is) these probabilities are still the same. That is what it means for $XY$ to be independent of $X$. The converse independence works similarly: after observing the value of $XY$ you would still assign prob 1/2 to event X = 1 and prob 1/2 to event X = -1. So $X$ is independent of $XY$ as well.

However, knowing both $X$ and $Y$ the distribution of $XY$ is quite different (concentrated in one point) than it was without this knowledge, so $X, Y, Z$ are not mutually independent.

Comment: Thank you, that is clear.

Comment: I expect you are correct in re-interpreting the question as discrete on $\{-1, 1\}$ rather than continuous on $[-1,1]$